# Find common elements in two files and unite them in one file

Tags: python

I have a tab-delimited file1,

```
marker1 transcript0 scaff1 1 24
marker2 transcript1 scaff2 1 53
marker3 transcript1 scaff2 1 53
marker4 transcript2 scaff3 1 89
marker5 transcript2 scaff3 1 89
marker6 transcript2 scaff3 1 89
```

and a file2,

```
contig1 transcript1 scaff2 1 53
contig2 transcript1 scaff2 1 53
contig3 transcript1 scaff2 1 53
contig4 transcript2 scaff3 1 89
```

My desired output file is,

```
transcript1 marker2 contig1 scaff2 1 53
transcript1 marker3 contig2 scaff2 1 53
transcript1 0       contig3 scaff2 1 53
transcript2 marker4 contig4 scaff3 1 89
transcript2 marker5 0       scaff3 1 89
transcript2 marker6 0       scaff3 1 89
```

Basically, I need to unite two files if there are transcripts in common. The two files have different lengths. I have tried using dictionary and join comman lines, but the results are no good. Can you give some inductions or ideas how can I do this on python?
I have tried join,

```
 join -1 2 -2 2 file1 file2
```

And this code,

```
f1=open('file1','r')
f2=open('file2','r')
output = open('common','w')

dictA= dict()
for line1 in f1:
    listA = line1.rstrip('\n').split('\t')
    dictA[listA[1]] = listA

for line1 in f2:
    new_list=line1.rstrip('\n').split('\t')
    query=new_list[0]
    subject=new_list[1]
    scaff=new_list[2]
    chrom=new_list[3]
    cm=new_list[4]
    if subject in dictA:
        listA = dictA[subject]
        output.write(subject+'\t'+query+'\t'+str(listA[0])+'\t'+str(listA[1])+'\t'+str(listA[2])+'\t'+str(listA[3])+'\t'+chrom+'\t'+cm+'\t'+scaff+'\n')
output.close()
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the code you have tried. Does it work?

Comment: What about `transcript0 marker1 0 scaff1 1 24`?

Comment: tobias_k, If there is a way to append it at the end good, otherwise I can leave them outside for now, since my file2 also contains transcripts that are not in file1

Comment: jonrsharpe, if you read a question carefully I am not asking to write me a code, a pseudocode or inductions like use this option or this one is enough for me. I think it is legitimate.

Comment: Do you want to "zip" the `marker` and `contig` columns together in the order they appear in the files? e.g. why is it `marker3 contig2; 0 contig3` and not the other way around?

Comment: Hi Mauris, I dont actually mind about the order, the most important point is that I can unite two files if there are transcripts in common

Comment: Are the other columns always the same of the transcript is the same? If not, do those have to match, too?

Comment: they are the same, but anyway they dont have to match, only transcrpts column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this (Python 3):

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import zip_longest

with open('file1', 'r') as f1, open('file2', 'r') as f2, \
                               open('common', 'w') as fout:
    remainder = {}
    markers = defaultdict(list)
    for line in f1:
        fields = line.split()
        markers[fields[1]].append(fields[0])
        remainder[fields[1]] = fields[2:]

    contigs = defaultdict(list)
    for line in f2:
        fields = line.split()
        contigs[fields[1]].append(fields[0])
        remainder[fields[1]] = fields[2:]

    print(remainder)
    transcripts = sorted(set(markers.keys()) | set(contigs.keys()))
    for transcript in transcripts:
        rest = remainder[transcript]
        zipped = zip_longest(markers[transcript], contigs[transcript],
                             fillvalue='0')
        for marker, contig in zipped:
            print(transcript, marker, contig, *rest, sep='\t')
```

Outputs:

```
transcript0 marker1 0   scaff1  1   24
transcript1 marker2 contig1 scaff2  1   53
transcript1 marker3 contig2 scaff2  1   53
transcript1 0   contig3 scaff2  1   53
transcript2 marker4 contig4 scaff3  1   89
transcript2 marker5 0   scaff3  1   89
transcript2 marker6 0   scaff3  1   89
```